# Relation of geometric and polyhedral convergence

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, lie-groups, geometric-group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry

By Proposition 3.10(i) of Jorgensen and Marden's 1990 *Algebraic and geometric convergence of Kleinian groups*, "[A] sequence $\{G_n\}$ of Kleinian groups converges geometrically to a Kleinian group if and only if $\{G_n\}$ converges polyhedrally to a Kleinian group. The geometric and polyhedral limits are the same." This fact is routinely cited in the literature of Kleinian groups, sometimes to bolster the *geometric topology*'s title, therein, to its name. What I've not seen is consideration of these two notions in greater generality:

- the geometric (also known as the Chabauty or Fell) topology makes good sense on the collection of discrete subgroups of any Lie group, for example, and
- Dirichlet fundamental domains (and hence questions of their convergence) make good sense on geodesically connected and complete finitely compact spaces (Ratcliffe, *Foundations of Hyperbolic Manifolds* 6.6.13),

so, to come to my question: what can we say of the relation between geometric and polyhedral convergence, or the associated topologies, more generally? For precision, I'm happy, at least at a first pass, restricting attention to the set of discrete subgroups of $\mathrm{Isom}^+(\mathbb{H}^n)$ for arbitrary $n$.

It is perhaps worth noting that the Jorgensen and Marden argument involves phenomena which seem to me (this is not my field) fairly unique to the $n=3$ case (Jorgensen's inequality, a universal ball).

I'd also be interested to know if the topologies in question generate the same Borel structure. Answers will probably follow from strong solutions to the main question, but there may be alternate paths to an answer.

Comment: Both Jorgensen inequality and existence of a universal ball are valid in higher dimensions as well, you just have to modify them appropriately.

Comment: I'm happy to hear this, would love to hear more (and/or of a reference). With the appropriate modifications, the Jorgensen-Marden argument goes through in all dimensions?